# jqGrid treeview multiple column sorting not working

Tags: jqgrid, treeview

I am using jqGrid treeview with sorting but after some analysis i found jqGrid treeview not working with multiple column sort.
How to do multisort in jqgrid treeview? Is there any way to do?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Can you please post your code?

Comment: I am using jqGrid 4.12.0 version

Comment: Sorry, we support commertial Guriddo jqGrid. Maybe Oleg (which maintain this free-jqGrid) will answer you.